# Copying the data in Excel through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

As you can see down, I am copy 4 columns of data from one workbook to another. I am stuck at a case where the destination has 8 columns and my area of columns are 1,2,5,7. can you suggest me some changes in the code please. The one below will work only for first 4 columns. Thanks.

```
Sub Copymc()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim rng As Range

Set x = Workbooks.Open("H:\testing\Q4 2014\US RMBS Q4.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("H:\testing\demo\test1.xlsx")

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long

x.Worksheets("RL Holdings").Activate
Range("A65536").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Range("A2:D" & LastRow).Copy   

y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line Range("A2:D" & LastRow).Copy has column D hardcoded into it.  This means that it will always copy A2 to D65536.  If you want specific columns(A, B, E, G) then I would recommend simply repeating your code for each column.

For example

```
Range("A65536").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.Copy
y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

then copy the code four times and replace the A to whatever column you want to copy or paste to.  If this isn't what you are looking for please elaborate on what you want.